# Removing a directory hangs

Tags: directory, rm, freeze

I'm a non-root user on a shared compile server that mounts `/home` via NFS from some other host. I have a directory `~/a/b` with lots of subdirectories `c1,c2,...`. I wanted to delete `~/a/b` completely, and succeeded for most of the `cN` directories. But a few (say `c1`) are completely inaccessible: I can execute them (i.e. `cd` into them) but neither list (`ls`) let alone remove them. If I say `rm -rf ~/a/b/c1`, the process hangs in a `D` state.

What can I do as a non-root user to get rid of `~/a/b`?

---

Update: I just ssh'd to the file-server (to rule out NFS) and I cannot perform the operation there either, so this doesn't seem to be an NFS problem after all. However, why does the kernel refuse to remove a directory?

Comment: I tagged this as [tag:sleep] because the process hangs in an uninterruptable sleep but there is no [tag:hangs] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a file or directory is an atomic operation requiring one system call, so if the `rm` command hangs, it's because the kernel is stuck. On an NFS filesystem, this can be (and usually is) due to the server not responding. On a local filesystem, this can be (and usually is) due to a hardware failure. Your disk is probably failing; the kernel logs would confirm that.

Comment: I left an `ls` command run in the background (in a screen, to be precise) and it actually terminated after a *very* long time (hours!), and showed a decent amount of (small) files (but nothing that would explain such a long waiting time). If the drive is broken, why does `ls` return after such a long time but not `rm`? Does that make any sense?

Comment: @bitmask It could be that some of the sectors where that directory is stored are damaged; the kernel retries disk accesses several times and manages to return some data about the directory, but when you try to write there the kernel never manages to accomplish anything. You really need to contact the system administrator and tell him to look at the kernel logs.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to be sure I couldn't fix that myself.

Answer (score 2):

If it hangs during find and delete operation, you can set a timeout for the process, as following (here I'm calling it through `bash` on windows with cygwin):

```
bash -c "find . -regex ".+fileDirToDelete" -exec rm -Rf {} \; & pid=$!; sleep 100; kill $pid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if any processes are accessing the files under the hood (like their current working directory). I would use tools like `lsof` and `fuser -v` and see if there are any processes messing up with the directory and get rid of them first. Restart nfs client service, if needed and try to check if the directory exists and more so do not remove the directory when it is a current working directory of the same shell.

Comment: Both `lsof` and `fuser -v` do not show processes for the directories. Also, that would not explain, why I cannot even list the directory contents. It feels like the directory is on a different file-system that is not connected, **but** that is definitely not the case.

Comment: you are right, I just corrected. Have you verified no process is accessing the filesystem, unmount filesystem, tried restarting the nfs client service and then remount filesystem?

Comment: As I said, I do not have root privileges.

Comment: Contact your root guy and tell him about this issue, it might be of his interest more to debug and resolve this at the earliest.

Comment: Already done :)